# NHibernate tries to insert when I do a select

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, hql

I'm using NHibernate 3.2

I'm on a transaction, saving some stuff, and before commiting, i'm trying to query some elements, which throws me an oracle insert error.

My query (HQL):

```
MySession = SessionFactory.OpenSession().BeginTransaction();
/*Do some saves but don't commit*/
var hql = @"select distinct c
from Car c inner join c.Manufacturer manuf where manuf.Id = 449" 
MySession.CreateQuery(hql).List<Car>(); /*throws error*/
```

When i execute this query, it throws me the following error

```
 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL  ...
```

My mappings are created with:

```
 lazy="true" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true"
```

Session Factory code:

```
 private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    var configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.Configure();
                    configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(EstoqueEquipamento).Assembly);
                    _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: When do you flush/commit your session?

Comment: Would be the line after my query, but it never gets there since an error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

the default behavior for NHibernate (FlashMode auto) is to perform a flush when performing a select - this does not include ISqlQueries. So, the moment you execute your hql query the flush occurs, in fact the flush occurs before the hql query execution.

This is probably irrelevant with the error, which only says that one of the entities that it tries to save has a NULL value in a property and the DB complains.

I should note here that you should probably match your DB constraints with your mappings

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues before due to inconsistent mappings, specifically I had a non null-able property mapped to a null-able database field. So when I retrieved the associated entity a default value was assigned to the property, which made nhibernate think the entity was dirty  so it was unexpectedly saving it. Could it be something similar?